# Nested SQL Query Will Not Execute

Tags: mysql, nested

Cannot execute this nested query.  FYI: All the table names and column names as well as search string are provided dynamically.

```
SELECT * from (
    SELECT * from employee WHERE 
        empno like '%al%' 
        OR name like '%al%' 
        OR job like '%al%' 
        OR boss like '%al%' 
        OR hiredate like '%al%' 
        OR salary like '%al%' 
        OR comm like '%al%' 
        OR deptno like '%al%' )
    WHERE name like 'al%' 
    union all SELECT * from 
    (SELECT * from employee WHERE
     empno like '%al%' 
        OR name like '%al%' 
        OR job like '%al%' 
        OR boss like '%al%' 
        OR hiredate like '%al%' 
        OR salary like '%al%' 
        OR comm like '%al%' 
        OR deptno like '%al%' ) 
    WHERE name like '%al%' and name not like 'al%'
```

I want to search a string(ex. "al") in all the columns(empno,name,job,boss,hiredate etc) of employee table.But the result should be displayed with respect to 'name' column.
The result should be displayed in following order:
1)firstly 'name' of the employees starting with 'al' in name column
and then
2)the 'name' of the employees containing 'al' anywhere in the name column.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  When posting a question, try to format any code/sql/scripts included so that they are more readable and include the text of your question in the body.  Are you receiving an error when running this query?  Please post that information as well.

Comment: What error are you receiving after running this query?

Comment: please provide sample data

Answer (score 0):

select * for employee WHERE name like 'al%'
UNION select * from employee WHERE 
name like '%al%'
UNION select * from employee WHERE 
  employee like '%al%'
OR job like '%al%'
OR boss like 'al%'
OR hiredate like '%al%'
OR deptno like '%al%'